# Clean Code - naming related classes

Tags: c#, refactoring

I've read *Clean Code* by *R.C. Martin* and I'm trying to adopt his suggestions about clean code as broadly as possible.

But I'm not sure how to name related classes.

Let's say I have a class named TreeDirectoryList.

I want to cut implementation of this class into many smaller classes.
Let's say I'll create a class named ParentIndexStack.

ParentIndexStack will implement functionality very dependent on TreeDirectoryList, so it's very not probable that this implementation of ParentIndexStack will be useful with any other class in the future.

But the name of ParentIndexStack is very generic, it's possible, that I'll need another class with the same name, within the same project.

So I thought I'll name **ParentIndexStack** more precise, like **TDLParentIndexStack**  (prefix TDL is from **TreeDirectoryList**).

Would it be correct ?

I'll end with many classes starting with TDLxxxxx.

Comment: If you do really need to create the ParentIndexStack class that has no application beyond the TreeDirectoryList - then you could create it as a private/protected nested class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to put that set of classes in their own namespace. Then you can have simple, concise names that still communicate the full meaning of the class through the namespace context.

Comment: +1. It's not incommon to see, even in the .NET framework, classes with the same name. As long as they are in a different namespace...

Comment: This reminds me of one of the things VB has that I wish C# would copy: the ability to import "relative" namespaces. So if I have two libraries in my solution that both have classes named `MyClass`, with naming patterns like `Company.ProductBrand.Library.Class`, I can import basic `Company.ProductBrand` namespaces and just say `Library1.MyClass` and `Library2.MyClass` instead of needing `Company.ProductBrand.Library1.MyClass` or an alias to distinguish them.